# Update list item using SharePoint List item

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, sha

I am trying to update SharePoint List Item using "UpdateListItems" method in Lists Web service.
CAML Query:

```
"<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
           "<Field Name='ID'>" + itemID + "</Field>" +
           "<Field Name='Status'>" + itemStatus + "</Field></Method>"
```

itemID,itemStatus and passed from UI as parameters.
This gives following  error

```
<Result ID="1,Update">
<ErrorCode>0x80070005</ErrorCode>
<ErrorText>The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred. (Result Code: 0x80070005)
</ErrorText>
</Result>
```

Can any one help.
One more question is the update method works only based on ID or is there any possibility of passing Title also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might not need at this moment, however this might be helpful for someone else facing the same issue.

Sometimes the reason for this error is the headers in the SOAP action. You need to set the following in order to make updates.:

beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");

I've created the following function to send updates at Sharepoint Lists:

```
function sendupdates(location,listName,command,fieldnames,fieldvalues){
      var updatesvar;
      for(x=0;x<fieldnames.length;x++){
      updatesvar =   updatesvar + '<Field Name="'+fieldnames[x]+'">'+fieldvalues[x]+'</Field>'
         }

      var batchvar = '<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="0"><Method ID="1" Cmd="'+command+'">'+updatesvar+'</Method></Batch>';

      var soapEnv =
                  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                  '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                  '<soap:Body>'+
                  '<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">'+
                  '<listName>'+listName+'</listName>'+
                  '<updates>'+batchvar+'</updates>'+
                  '</UpdateListItems>'+
                  '</soap:Body>'+
                  '</soap:Envelope>';

           $.ajax({
                  url: location+"/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
                  beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");},
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  data: soapEnv,
                  complete: complete,   
                  contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
              });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of this CAML tools:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648040.aspx